# Вывод единиц измерений

Tags: php, битрикс

Не получается вывести единицы измерения: кг и шт на сайте 1С-bitrix в поиске по сайту. Данные единицы измерения заполнены в торговом каталоге. Для вывода использую данное условие. Но ничего не выводит.

```html
<? if ($APPLICATION->GetGroupRight("main") >= "R" && $USER->IsAdmin()): ?>
                            <div class="search-result-item-info__price">
                                <a href="<? echo $arItem["URL"] ?>">
                                    <?= CCurrencyLang::CurrencyFormat($price['PRICE'], "RUB") ?>
                                    / <?= $item['ITEM_MEASURE']['TITLE'] ?>.
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        <? endif; ?>
```

Comment: Может, следует использовать $arItem, как двумя строками выше?

Comment: Там пришлось покапаться. Подключать модуль каталог и куча всего. Но вроде разобрался